# how to plot bar chart with integer on y axis and string on x axis in achrtengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I want to replace integer values on x axis with strings. I want to plot a bar chart between integer on y axis and strings on x axis. Please help me. Any help will be highly appreciated.[image: Like this bar chart having string on x axis and integer on y axis]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the default labels, you need to disable them and add custom labels:

```
renderer.setXLabels(0);
// call something like this for each label
renderer.addXTextLabel(x, "text");
```

Comment: I am fetching data from web services. The data need to be shown on y axis is in integer form but x axis data is in string form. what to do in that case?